# Python Yolov5 windowcapture module

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, yolov5

Attempting to use the yolov5windowdetect package with yolov5 for object detection but one of the imports is the "Screenshots" function from the "windowcapture" module. I'm using pycharms right now and can't find any module online or in the package manager with that name so I'm thinking it might be custom. Any ideas on how to find this file or alternative functions for the following code? The following includes all references to the "Screenshots" function.

```
from windowcapture import ScreenShots

    def get_adb_window(
        self,
        adb_path: str = r"C:\ProgramData\adb\adb.exe",
        adb_serial: str = "localhost:5555",
    ):
        self.sc = ScreenShots(hwnd=None, adb_path=adb_path, adb_serial=adb_serial)
        self.adb = True
        return self

    def get_hwnd_window(
        self, hwnd: Union[int, None] = None, window_title_regex: Union[str, None] = None
    ):
        self.sc = ScreenShots(hwnd=hwnd)
        if window_title_regex is not None:
            self.sc.find_window_with_regex(window_title_regex)
        return self
```

I tried installing basically every package with the words "windowcapture" to see if it might have been named differently.